# How to set multiple CC email recipients one message using webform in drupal 7

Tags: email, webforms, drupal-7, cc

My website using webform in drupal 7 application.

I have two queries

1. I can added a list for To email recipients one message. Email will receiving all the recipients but mails sending individual. I cant see in the to list group.
2. How to set multiple CC email recipients one message ? Here am using 'CC' => 'xx@yyyy.com, xx1@yyyy1.com, xx2@yyyy2.com' in theme_mail_headers under "$headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
function MODULENAME_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    if($key === 'MODULEcase') {
        $header = array(
            'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
            'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
            'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal',
            'Cc' => implode(',', $params['Cc']),  
        );
        $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
        $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
        }
        break;
    }
}

Then prepare data and pass to drupal_mail function
$mail_content = "Hello There!";
$params = array('body' => $mail_content);
$params['cc'] = array(
    'cc_user1@example.com',
    'cc_user2@example.com',
    'cc_user3@example.com',
);
$to =  'touser@example.com';  
$from = 'no-reply@example.com';
$mail = drupal_mail('MODULENAME', 'MODULEcase', $to, language_default(), $params, $from);

This is it. Enjoy :-)
```